# Storing data into an ArrayList upon every tick

Tags: java

Not sure if anybody could help me here, but im currently trying to make a something for a game. Here is something to briefly explain what im trying to do.

```
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onTick(TickEvent.RenderTickEvent e) {
        
        // RECORDING

        // on every tick, save xyz of myplayer
        // save yaw and pitch
        // capture if player is sprinting, walking forward and shifting.


        // REPLAYING

        // Check if my_XYZ current tick if not the same with a 0.5 threshhold, then its not longer replaying properly.
        // if xyz and yaw is the same, set current player yaw, and pitch to corresponding yaw/pitch and then just override all the movements.

    }
```

I have to save the players XYZ cords on everytick, and i feel like the best way to go about this is storing it in an arraylist, but unsure how i would go about doing this.

If someone could point me in the correct direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Upon further testing I haave gotten a little further, but still having a few difficulties.

```
ArrayList<Double> posX = new ArrayList<Double>(); // Create an ArrayList object

posX.add(mc.thePlayer.posX);

System.out.println(posX);
System.out.println(posX.size());
```

On everytick, it just overwrites whats currently in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the posX arraylist out of onTick(...) method. It would be better if you mark this list as final.